# How to get the common elements of the two sets in a Linked List?

Tags: c

I have got 2 linkedlist, I want to compare both lists and print every common element that appears in both list. tried everything can't get it to work.

```
struct Node *calcIntersection(struct Node *headA, struct Node *headB)
{

 struct Node * link1 = headA;

 struct Node * link2 = headB;

 while(link1 != NULL)
 {

  if (link2->value == link2->value)
     {

      printf("%d", link1->value);

     }      

    link1 = link1 -> pNext;

 }

  return link1;

}
```

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: it's not homework, trying to teach myself algorithms and data structures.

Comment: when comparing _every_ item in one collection, with _every_ item in another collection there must be **two loops** (somewhere), not one. So it has, at least, half of that.

Comment: Are the lists sorted? Is one of the lists sorted? Are you allowed to sort (or alter) them? What should happen if the lists contain duplicates, do you want the (partial) cartesian product in that case?

Comment: The list isn't sorted, don't really mind if it's sorted, just trying find the best way to get the common element from both sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, in reality your method should look like this:

```
struct Node *calcIntersection(struct Node *headA, struct Node *headB)
{
    struct Node *link1 = headA;

    while(link1 != NULL)
    {
        struct Node *link2 = headB;

        while (link2 != NULL)
        {
            if (link1->value == link2->value)
            {
              printf("%d", link1->value);
            }      

            link2 = link2->pNext;
        }

        link1 = link1->pNext;
    }

   return link1;
}
```

I'm not quite sure what you are returning there, but in most situations you will be returning NULL, I'm not quite sure if that's what you want however.

Comment: This is not a correct solution as both pointers advance at the same time. It only compares element by element. It fails for something like [1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3]

Comment: I see you edited your answer. The error I pointed out no longer applies. It should also be noted that repeated values are bound to be printed using this method.

Comment: Thank's got it working now, The return is support to return the common value.  What if the both set have more then 1 common element, do I just write another while loop to check for the 2nd set?

Comment: This approach has O(n^2) complexity. If you sort the lists first, you can improve this to O(n log n).

Answer (score 0):

OK.. This looks like homework.. so I will point out a few things that are pretty obvious in the code above

1) The condition you are checking for (link2->value == link2->value) is probably a typo. You might have meant link2->value == link1->value.
2) You are iterating over every element in list 1 but NOT in list 2. So you are checking only if the first element in list 2 is found in list 1.

I think this is sufficient.. for now.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (link2->value == link2->value)
```

Should be

```
if (link1->value == link2->value)
```

As pointed by gbulmer, you should also iterate over the second list and compare it to the first one.