# How to compare the strings of two linked lists?

Tags: c, string, linked-list, char, compare

While programming in C, I was able to store words (in the form of characters) into two linked lists that is only one char is stored per node, but its linked to another char and so on to form words, also i placed a number in between to separate the words . But I dont know how to fetch the words from the linked lists and compare it with all the words (chars of the other linked list) to see the total of number of occurences of that word from the first linked list, in the other linked list.

This is my first time using stack overflow so please accept my apologies if I have done something incorrectly.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814647/how-to-get-the-common-elements-of-the-two-sets-in-a-linked-list

Comment: Is there a specific reason for you to store words this way?

Comment: Also please show us some relevant code?

Comment: @kspree333: If you found my response helpful, could you please vote up my response and/or select it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

In the first linked list (call this "list A") that contains the word (I'll call it "word W") for which you are searching, keep a pointer to the first character in word W. Start at the beginning of the other list (call this "list B"). Declare a counter (call it "counter X") that will keep track of the number of instances of word W in list B. Step through both lists one character at a time, comparing each character. If you get to two characters in the list that don't match, reset the pointer in list A back to the beginning of the search word, and in list B skip to the beginning of the next word.  If you get to the end of both words, you have a match, so increment counter X. Once you get to the end of list B, you're done.